# Prevent Particles from Appearing Outside the mesh

Tags: particles

I'm trying to contain my grass particles inside a planter. but the particles are popping up outside of the mesh. How can I limit my particles to just the mesh face?
thank you![image]

Comment: Are you using geometry nodes or the hair system?

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't provide any useful information

Comment: I found the answer. The meshes that I was scattering had a lot of mesh surrounding the origin. turns out, the origins were never extending beyond the mesh, the models were because they were so wide. I trimmed the mesh to just around the origin and POOF, the scatter was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a hair particle system, you can do this with vertex groups. Make a vertex group set to just the area you want the grass to appear - and set all these vertices a weight of 1.

In your particle system, there is a tab called Vertex Groups. The Density one defines the areas from which your particles spawn and the density thereof. Set your new vertex group as the Density.

Now, you can adjust as needed - and even experiment with different weights to see how it looks with a variety of density as opposed to a blanket of 1.

Many forests and grasslands might look a little odd if the trees/grass are/is largely evenly spaced out, for example. Higher and lower densities within your vertices mean that you can have clumps of higher or lower density.